# How return response from a Kafka consumer to a RESTFUL request?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-rest

I am planning to develop an application where the request can be made by using a REST client (SpringBoot REST), eg to get the list of various services available based on a geographical code.

I am publishing this request as a message to Kafka. There is a consumer (Python code) that listens to this message, and on the arrival of the message it looks up various stores (NoSQL/HDFS), and get the list of services.

I've got this concept working up to the point where I have received the request, consumed it, and produce the results.

Where am not sure is how can the RestController/RestService know when the aggregation is completed and the results are ready, so that it can send the response back with the total size back to the browser?

Any ideas suggestions on this, please?

Comment: Hi, is using RabbitMQ an option here? I have a similar scenario and RabbitMQ has the mechanics to put it in place. If it is an option I can write a full answer where I describe what to do.

Comment: Thanks KLiff. Unfortunately no, as 'am tied to Kafka. However if you could mention how you handled it, i can check and see if i can replicate something similar in Kafka.

Comment: Hi, sure. 
The idea uses the routing capabilities of RabbitMQ. Routing is not something Kafka does. If you need to keep Kafka I would suggest to first explore Kafka Spring libraries that implement Request-Reply. I am not a Spring specialist but this subject has become mature enough to be completely handled by the library for the java side but not sure about the consumer (python) side.